# тип generic-параметр

Tags: java, рефлексия, generics

Интересует как можно определить тип generic-параметра с помощью Reflection в Java?
И есть ли для этого другие методы?

Comment: Да, можно определить, но лучше выложите немного кода, где нужно это сделать. Напр. в классе, методе...

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/66593/

Comment: Кода нету :(. Готовлюсь к собеседованию, наткнулся на этот вопрос, но ответа найти не смог.

Comment: если он вкомпилирован в класс (i.e. `ConcreteVariation extends Generic<String>`), то с помощью рефлексии просто получаете нужный тип как `ParametrizedType`, и уже из него вытаскиваете нужный параметр

Answer (score 2):

Есть дженерик:

```
public class SampleGeneric <T>{
    T t;
    public SampleGeneric(T t){
        this.t = t;
    }
}
```

Как узнать, какого типа у текущего объекта поле:

```
SampleGeneric<String> sample = new SampleGeneric<>("Test");

Class<? extends SampleGeneric> sampleClass = sample.getClass();
Field[] fields = sampleClass.getDeclaredFields();
for(Field f: fields){
    f.setAccessible(true);
    if(f.getName().equals("t")){
        try {
            Object get = f.get(sample);
            System.out.println(get.getClass().getName());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GenericReflectionTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно ещё взять объект, если есть геттер для поля - вызвать геттер. Результат положить в Object переменную. И и применить к ней медленный instanceof [Тип данных] в качестве проверки на принадлежность к интересующему известному типу. Но сие изврат есть. Подойдёт не всегда.