# Получение полей из ArrayList<?>

Tags: java

есть метод

```
   public static void test (ArrayList<?> list)
   {
    Field[] fields;
    if(list==null) return;

    if (list!=null && !list.isEmpty) 
    {
     fields = list.get[0].getClass().getFields(); 
    }

    if(list.isEmpty)
    {
     fields =  .... // тут собственно вопрос        
    }
    ... // далее заполняем файл определенного формата, зная тип, имя полей и их значения. Для пустого list тоже необходимо заполнить файл, в котором будет только шапка (названия колонок)

   }
```

Возможно ли найти поля '?' если list пустой?

Пример:
 есть класс

```
 public class Element {
 public int code = 0;
 public String name = "";
 }

ArrayList<Element> list = new ArrayList<>();
// не заполняем list; Вызываем метод test
test(list);
```

в результате получаем файл с колонками code , name.

Сейчас реализовал в виде:

```
 public static void <T> test (ArrayList<T> list, Class<T>  metaData)
{
'''
}
```

но интересует, возможно ли решить без параметра metaData?

Comment: Поля какого класса? что делает этот метод?

Comment: [`[java] [generics] is:q`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bgenerics%5D+is%3Aq)

Comment: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/591973/178988 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/365117/178988 3. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/365117/178988

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить Class дженерика?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/365117/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-class-%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)